# Loop does not iterate properly when exited

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, xna

My XNA program has a while loop (originally a for loop that had the same problem which I changed to allow cleaner exiting) that is supposed to loop through an array of class unitTank, find the first null entry and create a new object at that position, like so:

```
public void createBlueTank(float X, float Y)
{
    Boolean done = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < blueTank.Length - 1 && done == false)
    {
        if (blueTank[i] == null)
        {
            blueTank[i] = new unitTank(0, new Vector2(X, Y), this);
            done = true;
        }
        i++;

    }
}
```

`blueTank`'s creation method works fine (I have checked), the issue here is that if the loop includes any code that allows it to exit in any way, the prior code in the iteration doesn't get implemented. That is, if I remove the `done = true;` (or the `break` in the original for loop) then the loop creates a new `unitTank` for each null value in array blueTank in the manner intended, but if I change it to exit the loop after the first time this is done, it doesn't happen at all.

Additionally, I have noticed that if I change all the references to i *inside* the if statement after the check that `blueTank[i]` is null to `i+2` (because within the testing environment indexes 0 and 1 are defined, but 2 onwards are not); or if I change the initialisation of i to int `i = 2`, then the loop works as expected. Is this an issue with the if statement erroneously reading `blueTank[0]` as null, but the assignment statement not overwriting the existing instance inside that index, and then the loop getting cancelled before it ever reaches a truly null index? If so, why is this happening?

Comment: Debug the program, see what `i` is when the `if` is first true, see what value is in the array at that position, and see what the code is doing, line by line, during the loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to run into an issue with your while condition. `i < Length - 1`. Say Length is 10, meaning you have items 0 through 9. You tell it to stop when `i` is Less than Length - 1, which would give you 9. So you'll only iterate over items 0 through 8. Change it to either `i <= Length-1` or `i < Length`

Comment: Any reason you're not using a for loop? `for(int i = 0; i < blueTank.Length; i++) if(blueTanke[i] == null){ blueTank[i] = new tank...; break; }`

Comment: @sab669 Good call, that was left over from a variation on the loop I tried to solve the problem, I'll fix it now.

Comment: @NikoDrašković Because there will never be a situation where the method will be required to create more than one instance using the same location data, so I restructured the loop to exit while avoiding the use of `break;`, as per best practice, which involved making it a while loop.

Comment: Whoever said that you should avoid using break at all costs is an idiot. But even if you wanted to avoid it, which in this case you shouldn't, you could have just put the additional condition in the for loop. The code you have right now is just a for loop that is hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is this an issue with the if statement erroneously reading blueTank[0] as null, but the assignment statement not overwriting the existing instance inside that index,`

I think that it makes perfect sense that either `blueTank[0]` or `bluetank[1]` **actually is** `null` at that time.  Put a break-point in the debugger and you should be able to see which values are `null`

- [How to use the debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Comment: Why yes, yes that is exactly right. *Facepalm* I didn't even need to look at the debugger. For testing purposes, this code is called in the creation event of its parent object. I just moved the testing creation event of that object to after the creation assignment of blueTank[0] and blueTank[1] and it worked perfectly. This would have been a complete non-issue in final build. I am a doofus. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So just to rule out a simple typo as being the problem...   you are saying that this for loop doesn't work?

```
        for (var i = 0; i < blueTank.Length; i++)
        {
            if (blueTank[i] == null)
            {
                blueTank[i] = new unitTank(0, new Vector2(X, Y), this);
                break;  
            }
        }
```

Comment: He wrote that he originally used a for-loop and a break, this does not answer the question.